# Return type in typescript's arrow function

Tags: typescript

```
export const header = ():unknown => import('./header.vue')
```

not use 'unknown', what should i do?
I don't known how to write it.

Comment: What happens if you don't annotate it and just write `const header = () => import('./header.vue')`?  I don't have access to your file so it's hard for me to tell you what you should do... could you try to provide a [mre]?

Comment: `const header = () => import('./header.vue')` in typescript, it will tips you missing return type on function. my problem is how to define return type like this without use any or unknow

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand.  What does "tips you missing return type on function" mean?  Could you *show* it with a [mre] that others can view in their own IDEs?  If not, then I'm not sure how anyone else can help you.